# (MMD) How do I make multiple empties (joints) and meshes (rigid bodies) visible at once?

Tags: physics, visibility

I imported a(n MMD) model with accurate physics, but everything that controls it (rigid bodies = ovals, joints = right angle things) was instantly made invisible. There are over a hundred of each. How do I make every selected "object" (rigids, joints) visible quickly for easy repositioning? Thanks!

EDIT: Blender seems to treat joints as empties and rigid bodies as meshes (though Idk why they look low-poly in Edit mode and subdivided/smooth in Object mode). These two things define physics (collisions, cloth, etc) in MMD.

[image]

Comment: A little more inspection says the joints are considered empties and rigids are considered meshes (with invisible subdivide modifiers?) in Blender, though I want to toggle all their visibilities at once more than their shapes right now. These items define physics behavior in MMD.

Comment: The command appears to be Shift+G for v2.90, and the tooltip says that only works for visible items, which of course doesn't apply here.

Comment: yes my bad, and I didn't see any proper way to do what you wanted, it looks like you've found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, the quickest answer was MMD/plugin-specific. Anyone using MMD models in Blender needs to have mmd_tools installed ([Powroupi](https://github.com/powroupi/blender_mmd_tools) has the most updated version now). Installation provides an MMD and a Misc tab in the <kbd>N</kbd> menu, and Misc > MMD Display has checkboxes to make all rigids and joints instantly visible, at which point they can be grouped and manipulated en masse.